# Trying to interface with an Aanderaa RCM9

Tags: serial-port

I have an older Aanderaa RCM9 (https://epic.awi.de/id/eprint/45145/1/RCM9.pdf) that is missing its Data Storage Unit and its reader. They don't produce these anymore nor do they service the model. It would be a shame to toss an otherwise nice piece of equipment, so I thought to try and get a serial feed from the terminal or DSU output and log on an Arduino with an SD card. I have tried to connect with a TTL-RS232 converter, and there seems to be a consistent Tx from the instrument, it comes in batches, but reads out in CoolTerm as "............" I've tried different terminal configurations, and connections, but that's the best I get. Here's how it looks inside: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DV5e0.jpg
Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid that the output is the old Aanderaa PDC4 serial format where long pulses (81ms) represents zeros and short (27ms) represents ones in a 10 bit binary word framed in a 4 second window.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So I guess the only thing to do is to find an old Aanderaa reader?

Comment: That's one possibility. With some Arduino programming it should also be possible to read, decode and log the PDC 4 signal.

Comment: Decoding a binary signal sounds daunting, mostly because I haven't tried that before... thanks though!